# How to normalize negative number in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, normalize

I have video features as numpy files (.npy) with the shape of **(15, 2048)** with positive and negative value. I want to normalize it so that **all the values are positive only**. The numpy array is something like this:

```
array([[-1.4004713 ,  0.6517762 , -0.11610898, ...,  0.3231497 ,
         0.10557604, -1.0216804 ],
       [-0.34153703,  1.2883852 ,  0.16293666, ..., -0.53560203,
        -0.067341  ,  0.00724552],
       [ 0.877613  ,  0.11527498, -0.45193946, ..., -0.16771363,
         0.38475066, -0.284884  ],
       ...,
       [-0.5748145 ,  0.08665206,  0.27134556, ..., -0.03541826,
         0.05377219, -0.62528425],
       [-0.02782645, -0.04130568, -0.0581201 , ...,  1.2714614 ,
         0.7328908 ,  0.2180524 ],
       [-0.28007308,  1.2357589 , -0.04791486, ...,  0.14003311,
         1.0041502 , -0.47158736]], dtype=float32)
```

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
 Result = np.where(a >= 0, a/np.max(a), -a/np.min(a))
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the absolute value and then normalize?

Comment: [Numpy absolute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) will convert everything to a positive value. If you then want to normalize the array have a look at [sklearn's normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

Comment: I do not want absolute value,  I want normalization. I tried this code:  Result = np.where(a >= 0, a/np.max(a), -a/np.min(a))     but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own? Usually people show their code and explain what didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to normalize to the global min and max, and there are no NaNs, the normalized array is given by:

```py
(arr - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min())
```

If you have NaNs, rephrase this with `np.nanmin()` and `np.nanmax()`.